# Absolute Phrase Grammar

Tags: grammar

Q1: Are both these sentences correct?

Q2: When should we use "with" in this structure?

Q3: Is there any difference in meaning?

(1) Her eyes glistening with tears, she stood up and turned away from the people.

(2) With her eyes glistening with tears, she stood up and turned away from the people.

Source: [http://www.csun.edu/~bashforth/305_PDF/305_PDF_Grammar/ParticiplePhrasesAsReducedARelatives.pdf](http://www.csun.edu/%7Ebashforth/305_PDF/305_PDF_Grammar/ParticiplePhrasesAsReducedARelatives.pdf)

Comment: Using _with_ in sentences like this is optional.

Comment: @KateBunting   There's a specific episode of Star Trek TNG you're making me think of, right now. :p

Comment: @Sapere_aude This isn't really an answer  to your question, but consider putting your participle phrases at the end (or in the middle) of sentences. "She stood up and turned away from the people, her eyes glistening with tears."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of ***labels,*** the two constructions are different...

> 1. ***Her eyes glistening with tears**, she stood up and left*.
>    is a [***participial / participle** clause*](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/prepositional-phrase/)
> 2. ***With her eyes glistening with tears**, she stood up and left*.
>    is a [***prepositional** clause*](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/prepositional-phrase/)

...but *functionally* and *semantically* they're equivalent and interchangeable ***adverbial*** elements which both tell us ***how*** she left / ***her condition*** when she left. The only difference is the terminology.

Note that most native speakers wouldn't particularly notice the repetition of ***with*** in such contexts - and if even if they *did*, most would think nothing of it.